# Error after redirection - "cannot determine loading status"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I need some help with Selenium/PyCharm. After switching to a new PC, the code that used to work fine began to break when searching for a button and clicking on it. Interesting thing: problem arise only on this button, i would say even on redirection. if you skip this step, everything works perfectly.

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "phone").send_keys("0991041337")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("Login123")
button_login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "submit-login").click()
time.sleep(1)
```

[A screenshot of the error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQZOH.png)

I will be very grateful if someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a relatively new Selenium bug where `cannot determine loading status` appears, even though the click was successful. This will get around your issue:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "phone").send_keys("0991041337")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").input2_pw.send_keys("Login123")
button_login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "submit-login")

from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

try:
    button_login.click()
except WebDriverException as e:
    if "cannot determine loading status" in e.msg:
        pass  # Odd issue where the click did happen. Continue.
    else:
        raise e
```

I'm the maintainer of [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), so I patched the issue directly in https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/1374